# Extract text between two markers and replace a character

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to change

```
>lcl|ORF183:9482:8118 unnamed protein product
```

into

```
>ORF183:9482-8118
```

Keep everything after `|` and before 'white space', plus replacing second `:` to `-`

So far I'm doing it with the following code:

```
sed -e '/^>/s/ .*//' -e '/^>/s/|/ /' -e '/^>/s/lcl //' -e '/^>/s/\(.*\):/\1-/'
```

but wish to do it in a simpler one-line code.

Comment: With awk: `awk -F '[| ]' '{print ">" $2}'`

Comment: `sed -e 's/>lcl|ORF183:9482:8118 unnamed protein product/>ORF183:9482:8118/'`

Comment: Welcome to the site! You should be aware that regular expressions are made to recognize patterns, we can't assume which characters will vary and which will always stay in place, so we can't give an elegant solution that you can use on other examples without additional information from you.
I recommend you try the website regexr.com, use control groups and play around.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*|\)\(.*\):\(.*\):\(.*\)[[:space:]]\(unnamed.*$\)/>\2:\3-\4/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some improvements based on code you've tried

```
$ sed -e '/^>/s/ .*//' -e '/^>/s/lcl|//' -e '/^>/s/:/-/2' ip.txt
>ORF183:9482-8118
```

- `-e '/^>/s/|/ /' -e '/^>/s/lcl //'` can be simplified to `-e '/^>/s/lcl|//'`

  - use `s/>[^|]*|/>/` if you wish to match any text between `>` and `|`
- `sed` allows to specify which occurrence of the match you want to replace, `s/:/-/2` means replace the 2nd `:` to `-`

If your `sed` implementation allows grouping, you can group all the commands (separated by `;`) inside `{}` for a particular address

```
$ sed '/^>/{s/ .*//; s/lcl|//; s/:/-/2}' ip.txt
>ORF183:9482-8118
```

Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources and other goodies